# migration from oracle to sql server 2008

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2008, migration

Are there any tools that I can use to migrate my Oracle database to SQL Server 2008? If not what are other choices for this type of migration?

With migration I need to move only tables (with all indexes and constraints) and data. There are no any functions, views or stored procedures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See e.g.

*Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant (SSMA) for Oracle is a free tool for migrating Oracle databases to Microsoft SQL Server. SSMA for Oracle converts Oracle database objects (including stored procedures) to SQL Server database objects, loads those objects into SQL Server, migrates data from Oracle to SQL Server, and then validates the migration of code and data.*

http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/migration-oracle.aspx

or many more commercial offerings - Bing or Google are your friends!